# Magento2.1 Modifications on js file missing after content deploy

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have installed Magento 2.1.2 with Clickboom Magento Theme.

I did some modifications on following java script file under pub static folder.

`pub/static/frontend/Sm/clickboom/en_US/Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

But after running php `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` I lost all modifications.

Where i can modify this javascript.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content in pub/static is generated/copied from sources.

Looks like pub/static/frontend/Sm/clickboom/en_US/Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js is from Magento/Catalog module and folder /view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js.

see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html for more detail

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify any files under the `pub` folder.

you can modify this js at:

```
app/design/frontend/Sm/clickboom/Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

if you can not fine this file at above path then go to the parent theme which you difine in:

```
app/design/frontend/Sm/clickboom/theme.xml
```

OR copy file from below path and add above path:

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\web\js
```

- deploy content again and clear cache